# Close open generic types with whatever is requested, by calling a lambda

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am currently using the [mongodb-csharp](https://github.com/mongodb-csharp/mongodb-csharp) drivers in my application.

I would like my repositories to depend on `IMongoCollection<T>`, and I'm trying to figure out how to configure StructureMap to let me call a lambda when it is requested. For a non-open-generic type, I have it setup like this:

```
For<IMongoDatabase>()
            .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use(cx =>
                     {
                         var mongo = cx.GetInstance<IMongo>();
                         return mongo.GetDatabase("TestDB");
                     });
```

I would like to configure StructureMap to do something like the above with open generics, however I'm not sure how to get the type that was requested:

```
For(typeof (IMongoCollection<>))
            .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use(cx =>
                     {
                         var db = cx.GetInstance<IMongoDatabase>();
                         // How do I figure out what to close the generic with?
                         return db.GetCollection<T>();
                     });
```

Is this possible with StructureMap? I feel like I'm missing something here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no completely reliable way to determine the requested type -- a limitation I have also run into. I do not imagine it will be fixed until StructureMap 3.0.
However, you might be able to find it by looking at the cx.BuildStack.Root.RequestedType (or other frames on the BuildStack - not always the root). I haven't had great luck with that approach, but it is worth experimenting with.

For your scenario, I would probably just have my consumers accept an `IMongDatabase` and call `GetCollection` themselves. It feels a little strange to inject "data" (in the form of `IMongCollection`) via your IOC.

Comment: I went ahead and injected `IMongoDatabase` as you suggested, it just seemed strange to have all of my method start out with the same `var collection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Message>();` I do agree with you about it being a little strange to inject the collection, though.